# How to send the data inside a list to kafka as a record

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm new to scala,
I have a List like this

```scala
newlist = List([Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Name], [2012-08-13T00:00:00.000Z,92.29,92.59,91.74,92.4,2075391.0,MMM], [2012-08-14T00:00:00.000Z,92.36,92.5,92.01,92.3,1843476.0,MMM], [2012-08-15T00:00:00.000Z,92.0,92.74,91.94,92.54,1983395.0,MMM], [2012-08-16T00:00:00.000Z,92.75,93.87,92.21,93.74,3395145.0,MMM], [2012-08-17T00:00:00.000Z,93.93,94.3,93.59,94.24,3069513.0,MMM], [2012-08-20T00:00:00.000Z,94.0,94.17,93.55,93.89,1640008.0,MMM])
```

I use the below code to send the data inside a list to Kafka

```
      val today = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
      val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      val key = UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")(0)

      val value = formatter.format(today) + "," + newList

      val data = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, value)

      println(data.value())
      producer.send(data)
```

and my output is like below:

```
2020-05-12 14:56:41,List([Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Name], [2012-08-13T00:00:00.000Z,92.29,92.59,91.74,92.4,2075391.0,MMM], [2012-08-14T00:00:00.000Z,92.36,92.5,92.01,92.3,1843476.0,MMM], [2012-08-15T00:00:00.000Z,92.0,92.74,91.94,92.54,1983395.0,MMM], [2012-08-16T00:00:00.000Z,92.75,93.87,92.21,93.74,3395145.0,MMM], [2012-08-17T00:00:00.000Z,93.93,94.3,93.59,94.24,3069513.0,MMM], [2012-08-20T00:00:00.000Z,94.0,94.17,93.55,93.89,1640008.0,MMM])
2020-05-12 14:56:42,List([Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Name], [2012-08-13T00:00:00.000Z,92.29,92.59,91.74,92.4,2075391.0,MMM], [2012-08-14T00:00:00.000Z,92.36,92.5,92.01,92.3,1843476.0,MMM], [2012-08-15T00:00:00.000Z,92.0,92.74,91.94,92.54,1983395.0,MMM], [2012-08-16T00:00:00.000Z,92.75,93.87,92.21,93.74,3395145.0,MMM], [2012-08-17T00:00:00.000Z,93.93,94.3,93.59,94.24,3069513.0,MMM], [2012-08-20T00:00:00.000Z,94.0,94.17,93.55,93.89,1640008.0,MMM])
```

But I want my output to be like this(each value of a list as row):

```
2020-05-12 14:56:41,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Name
2020-05-12 14:56:42,2012-08-13T00:00:00.000Z,92.29,92.59,91.74,92.4,2075391.0,MMM
2020-05-12 14:56:43,2012-08-14T00:00:00.000Z,92.36,92.5,92.01,92.3,1843476.0,MMM
```

How can we do that? Please ignore my mistakes

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420634/how-to-efficiently-send-messages-out-of-a-seqstring-to-kafka

Comment: I don't really understand your types. This is a List of what?

Comment: @mike, unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProducerRecord is  a instance for a single data 
If You want to send  list of data, multiple call 'send' method

```
newlist.map(row => 
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, row.mkString))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it gives me output without space like this: DateOpenHighLowCloseVolumeName
2012-08-13T00:00:00.000Z92.2992.5991.7492.42075391.0MMM,

I want space or comma between each values like this: 
Date Open High Low Close Volume Name
2012-08-13T00:00:00.000Z 92.29 92.59 91.74 92.420753 91.0MMM
Can you help me with that

Comment: that is sacla programming  grammer issue. 
If You use `List("A","B").mkString(", ")`  then You see "A, B"